# How to generate asset URL from within a service?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 and I want to generate the absolute url to an asset from a service class, not a template. I'd like the same thing that

```
{{ asset('/path/to/my/asset') }}
```

would return in a template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at:
Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Extension/AssetExtension

```
public function getAssetUrl($path, $packageName = null)
{
    return $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path, $packageName);
}
```

Basically, inject templating.helper.assets into your service then call getUrl.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I just want to add that I needed to put `strict="false"` in the service argument for **templating.helper.assets** for it to inject properly. It works fine now.

Comment: How do I get an absolute URL?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple and clean way for Symfony 2.8:

services.yml:

```
arguments:
    assets: "@templating.helper.assets"
```

In the service:

```
protected $assets;

public function __construct($assets)
{
    $this->assets = $assets;
}
```

Then you can use it in any function of the service like this:

```
$this->assets->getUrl('myurl');
```

Comment: In Symfony 3.X the service `templating.helper.assets` has been removed and replaced by `assets.packages`.

Comment: You could update the answer using the service's hint typing.